# Which many-to-one IPC for C daemon

Tags: c, linux, unix, ipc, c99

I have a daemon running which takes input from multiple process and parses them. The inputs are a task name and a message from each running thread. They are divided in two category.

I have though of a temp dir with one file per process, but how to indicate the dir to the other processes? In a FIFO, how to identify each process? by PID?

What IPC should I choose and why?

Comment: If this is on one host, use Unix domain sockets.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thank you. I considered TCP connections but considered them too slow. Now, that is a great option: combined with fork() I can make one process per connection.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX queues can be used (if available on your platform). The daemon would read from the queue, and each task could write its pid, name, and message.